# Schema with records referring to each other

Tags: avro

I have an schema where I have two records with field that contain elements of each other. How do you forward declare a record in Avro so that you can use its declaration before it is defined.

```
  {
"namespace": "mytest",
"name": "Foo",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
  {"name" : "bar", "type": ["null", "Bar"]}
],

"name": "Bar",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
  {"name" : "foo", "type": ["null", "Foo"]}
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use record statements in schema as you did.

I think you need a schema like this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Foo",
  "namespace": "q44820145",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Bar",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "foo",
            "type": ["null", "Foo"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have seen this syntax before however I was looking for a way so I could keep each definition in its own file. However working on the tweeter API I am still able to refer to the inner declaration in other files. So I guest this is the best we have today. So I will mark this as an answer.